# r plotting multiple columns in df through a loop

Tags: r, loops, plot

```
a<-c(1,2,3,4) 
b<-c(1,2,3,4) 
c<-c(2,3,4,5)
f<-c(5,6,7,8)
p<-c(3,7,6,5)
df = data.frame(a,b,c,f,p)

for (i in c('c','f','p'))
    plot(df$a, df$i)
```

I am trying to use a loop to plot some columns of a `df` but `df$columnName` does not appear to select the correct columns.

I have also tried `plot(a~i, df)` and it does not work also. Please help!

Comment: Do you need `matplot('colnames<-'(t(df[-1]), df$a), type = 'l')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can use the df$ style of indexing for some variable that holds a string. If you switch to square brackets for column indexing (making sure not to forget the empty row index to select all rows) then you can use a variable holding a column name.

The following works to make three plots of the variables in your vector:

```
par(mfrow=c(3,1))
for (i in c('c','f','p'))
    plot(df[,'a'], df[,i])
```